# How to send parameter that is part of url in httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, httparty

I want to make a request to a URL:

```
url = http://localhost:3000/api/v1/new_car/car_makes/:make/detail
```

When I run:

```
query[:make] = "honda"
HTTParty.get(url, :query => query, :headers => @headers)
```

I receive:

```
params[:make] #=> nil
```

and receive the parameter value:

```
params["make"] #=> ":make"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
    params = params.with_indifferent_access
```

you will be able to access in both ways

```
    params["make"] and params[:make]
```

Comment: can you explain it.. how can I do it?

Comment: what is with_indifferent_access

Comment: basically issue is that I am not getting honda which I pass for :make

Comment: hash keys can be string(params["make"]) or symbols(params[:make]) . JSON data received as params will always have keys in string format. When you do params = params.with_indifferent_access , params can be accessed with both keys as string and symbol .